Runtime registration, register a new instance on runtime. (autofac)
I use DI to decouple some services from the rest of the application. I register them at the composition root of the project and read their configurations from the database. I would like to implement a feature that allows clients to add new configurations to databases, then call APIs and have them register as new instances. In the old version of Autofac, I used to do this, but they removed it in the new version.
this is my setup in composition root (Startup.cs):
  using (var context = new MyDbContext(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")))
  {
     var serviceConfigurations = GetServiceConfiguationFromContext(context);

     foreach(var config in serviceConfigurations) 
     {
          builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
                          .As<IService>()
                          .WithParameter((info, context) => 
                                info.ParameterType == typeof(ServiceConfiguration),
                                       (info, context) => config)
                                                 .SingleInstance();
     }

  }

This allows me to create multiple instances of MyService with different parameters from the database. and I'm using my services this way:
  public class SomeClass 
  {
     private readonly IList<IService> _services;
     public SomeClass(IList<IService> services)
     {
        _services = services
     }

     public asyn Task DoSomething()
     {
        await Task.WhenAll(_services.Select(a=> a.DoSomething()))
     }
  }

I could add a configuration on runtime with code like this with the previous version of Autofac:
  public void RegisterService(IContainer container, ServiceConfiguration config)
  {
      var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
      containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyService>()
                   .As<IService>()
                   .WithParameter((pn, ctx) => 
                       pn.ParameterType == typeof(ServiceConfiguration), 
                       (pn, ctx) => config)
                          .SingleInstance();
      containerBuilder.Update(container);
  }

By using this method, I was able to provide an API to the client and when they call it, it registers the new instance with a new parameter of the data from the database.
Since I updated my project to .Net 8 and updated Autofac, I am no longer able to do this since containerBuilder.Update() has been removed from Autofac version 5.
Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution after spending couple of hours searching.
Is there a solution to this problem?

So you're registering a dynamic number of instances of the same MyService type, where their only difference is the injection of a different ServiceConfiguration instance? In that case, I suggest changing the design such where you keep the ServiceConfiguration runtime data objects out of the composition phase, hide their loading behind an abstraction of some sort and perhaps replace IList<IService> with a custom abstraction, such that SomeClass doesn't have to work with a list of IService instances. Unfortunately,your question doesn't give enough details to give more concrete advise

@Steven I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I apologize if my question is unclear. MyService is not the only type, I just wanted to make things easier. It is for the implementation of a third-party application. It is a kind of ACL (it is for searching for a product available in some third-party service). A ServiceConfiguration is a collection of settings for calling those providers, such as BaseUrl, Username, etc. I want to inject all instances of my services and search from all of them, and I don't want to directly reference those services to avoid high coupling.

@Steven I have MyService1, MyService2 and MyService3 (the numbers are static and cannot be changed), but you can have multiple instances with different settings. Imagine I need to implement an ACL for Amazon, Flipkart, and Myntra, and each of them has an interface named ISearchingProduct. I would like to add more credentials to Amazon so I can have better pricing on some products. My solution is to register multiple Amazon implementations and then determine which is the best from the results.
